# Vim buffer full despite new file

Tags: vim

Upon opening any file or even creating a completely new file, I have some stuff in my vim buffer. Surely once I open a new file, I ought to get an empty buffer? I am rather perplexed at what is going on here. More importantly, I want to get rid of this. How do I empty whatever is polluting my buffers?

Comment: what is the stuff appearing? Is it consistent (the same every time)?

Comment: Yep. Seems to be a file I edited at some point.

Comment: Do you have any .vimrc or .viminfo or .vim directory in your home?

Comment: Yes, I do have a .vimrc file.

Comment: @ChrisvCB: What's the output of :ls?